# Twitter search word analysis

Tags: python, twitter, analysis

I'm attempting some word analysis on a large collection of tweets.

I'm pulling tweets based on a search query, I then want to somehow find the keywords that appear often and that are related to the original query.

I'm not quite sure how to go about this in a reasonably effective manner though. I'm currently just removing stopwords then finding the words that occur most, but this is a bit more basic than I'd like.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this sort of thing (or even links to any reading on the topic)?

Any help greatly appreciated.

(my implementation is in Python, if that's relevant)

Comment: Read "Programming Collective Intelligence" - I think Bayesian document classifier is what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For semantic reasoning about the content of a tweet, you should definitely try [the NLTK (Natural Language Toolkit Package)](http://nltk.org/). It's capable of quite sophisticated analysis of text.

Comment: I had to do something very similar about a year ago. NLTK was very useful.

Comment: Ah, okay. I've used NLTK for some basic stuff before. I've never looked into it's more in-depth features though. I shall do so, thanks!